# latexmk creates multiple .fls files in dropbox

Tags: latexmk, dropbox

I use the lightweight Gummi Tex editor on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I'm having a very weird problem. It creates multiple .FLS files automatically when I meet these two conditions:

1 - When I'm working on a TeX file located in dropbox or pclouddrive (which is an alternative to dropbox), and

2 - When I compile with Latexmk

I'm guessing that latexmk has some issues with cloud storage services such as dropbox? It keeps creating new .fls files every time I type something. This is not the case when I'm working on a Tex file that is in my local hard drive.

**

### Edit (Aug 9):

**

I do have latexmk on two machines (my laptop at school and desktop at home) , but I do not use them simultaneously as I only need to use one machine at a time.

The cloud storage service that I use is [pClouddrive](https://www.pcloud.com/) - it's similar to Dropbox but cheaper, more secure, and works nicely with Linux. My system is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

You're right - it looks like the FLS files are created by pdflatex (their filenames begin with pdflatex). However, this only happens when I select latexmk as the compiler like this:
[image]

By multiple files, I mean that these fls are automatically created every few seconds (whenever I type anything new in the TeX document). See the screenshots below - the directory for the TeX file is on the left and the TeX editor (gummi) is on the right. Notice how it has one fls file on the first screenshot, when I begin using the TeX file. More and more FLS files are created every time I enter a new sentence:

Sentence 1 (only one .fls file):
[image]

Sentence 2 (more .fls files):
[image]

Sentence 3 (even more .fls files):
[image]

Finally, this is what the FLS files look like when I open them:

[image]

All of these files begin with the prefix pdflatex, but this problem happens only when I pick latexmk as the compiler.

Any help with this would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Latexmk shouldn't have any problems with Dropbox.  I use it regularly for projects stored on Dropbox. One thing that does cause trouble is having latexmk simultaneously running on more than one computer accessing the same document on Dropbox; that has to be avoided.  Actually the .fls files are created by pdflatex (or ...), during compilation of the document, not by latexmk itself. So we're going to need more details to diagnose this. What exactly do you mean by "multiple .fls files"? What names do they have, or how do you know they are multiple files?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I edited the post since it took too many characters to explain. Please see the post above.

Comment: The contents of the fls file show some anomalous features. The working directory is the location of your file, but the input document file has the name .Example.tex.swp instead of Example.tex. There are files read and written in .cache/gummi instead of the document directory. This suggests Gummi is doing something that is not a standard compilation. Further information needed: What command line is Gummi using to invoke latexmk?  (There should be some configuration setting where you can find this.) Do you have any latexmkrc files for configuring latexmk?  If so what are the contents?

Comment: The extra fls files you are seeing have a name of the form 'pdflatex' following by an integer and '.fls'.  Such a file is initially created by pdflatex when it is invoked with the -recorder option (as latexmk does).  The integer is the process ID for the run of pdflatex. Normally, pdflatex quickly renames to base.fls, where base.tex is the name of the TeX file that is being compiled. That renaming fails here, for reasons I don't know. It could be an interaction with Gummi and/or pCloudDrive (as distinct from Dropbox).

Comment: One further idea: What happens when you compile the same file from the command line, using latexmk?  That should sort out whether the problem is simply with the use of pClouddrive or whether it is Gummi and pCloulddrive.

Comment: Not sure if is relevant, but I have a project on Dropbox and compile from CLI using Makefile/latexmk. Everytime I recompile a main.fls is created and then deleted (I always get a Dropbox notification a few seconds after compiling saying *you deleted main.fls*).